# Flutter/Dart How to adjust Modalbottomsheet animation speed?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart, animation, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I read this reference

```
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html
```

it says "transitionAnimationController parameters can be passed in to customize the appearance and behavior of modal bottom sheets.
The transitionAnimationController controls the bottom sheet's entrance and exit animations if provided."

but, I couldn't find any reference of transitionAnimationController,

so my question is, **How can I adjust ModalBottomSheet Animation(entrance and exit speed that I want to adjust) with transitionAnimationController?**

thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using a StatefulWidget add `with TickerProviderStateMixin` and create an `AnimationController` with `BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this)`. You can then set the `duration` on the AnimationController. In this example I've set the duration to 3 seconds.

Make sure you dispose the AnimationController in `void dispose ()`

```
class MyModalBottomButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyModalBottomButtonState createState() => _MyModalBottomButtonState();
}

class _MyModalBottomButtonState extends State<MyModalBottomButton>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller =
        BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this);
    controller.duration = Duration(seconds: 3);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      child: Text("Show bottom sheet"),
      onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        transitionAnimationController: controller,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            child: Text("Your bottom sheet"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it solved my problem. you are the best!

Comment: it solves the problem but after you close it it wont let you reopen it for some assertion error

Comment: Exception caught by gesture ══════════════════════════════════════════════     
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
AnimationController.forward() called after AnimationController.dispose()
AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.
'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 455 pos 7: '_ticker != null'

Comment: @Angelica I got the same issue. temporary solution is to add listener again in onComplete 

```showModalBottomSheet().whenComplete(() {controller =BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this);});```

Comment: how can I change the closing animation of bottomSheet!

Comment: For changing the closing animation, you have to use reverse duration
`controller = BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this);
controller.duration = Duration(seconds: 3);
controller.reverseDuration = Duration(seconds: 3);`